# Mongoid: Run callback from embedded document on parent

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Rails 3.0.1
Mongoid (2.0.0.beta.20)

Class Post
     embeds_many :comments
     field :comments_count
    end

```
Class Comment
 embedded_in :commentable, :inverse_of => :comments
end
```

I want to select the 10 most commented posts. To do that I need comments_count field in Post. But since my Comment is polymorphic (Post.comments, Message.comments etc) I don't want create inc callbacks in Post. What I wan't to do is create callback in Comment which will update comment_count field in Post.

I don't know how I can perform inc operation in embedded document on Field from parrent document and execute this callback from parrent document

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how to increment the `Post` from the embedded polymorphic `Comment`:

```
Class Comment
  after_create :update_post_comment_count

  def update_post_comment_count
    if self._parent.class == Post
      Post.collection.update( {'_id' => self._parent._id}, 
                              {'$inc' => {'comment_count' => 1}} )
    end
  end
end
```

I am pretty sure that this callback will execute whenever a new Comment is created so I don't think you need to worry about executing it from the parent document. Let me know if it works.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498796/trigging-after-save-on-an-embedded-item-when-assigning-it-via-in-mongoid/4244223#4244223) and this [Github issue](http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/173) for more info on callbacks in embedded documents.

Comment: Thank you that code work for me :]. Do you have link to mongodb documentation with _parent methods description ?

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation for `_parent` . I found it myself through trial and error.